# Geocodificar una dirección

Tags: php, geocodificación

Hola a todos: tengo un simple campo de texto y un botón. 
En el campo de texto el usuario puede ingresar una dirección y cuando presiona el botón, lo que hago es geocodificar la dirección para obtener las coordenadas geográficas. Para obtenerlas hago lo siguiente:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=";
$address = $_POST['address'];
$call = $url.urlencode($address);
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($call), true);

if($response['status'] != 'OK') {
    echo "No ha sido posible geocodificar la dirección. Por favor, vuelve a introducir los datos. ";       
    exit;
}

}


?>
```

Ahora bien, se que en la variable response tengo las coordenadas, pero no sé cómo mostrarlas, cómo obtenerlas... 
Me pueden dar una mano ?

PD: probé poner una variable "$longitud" y le hice un "count($response)" y me devolvió un "2" es decir, que ahi estan las coordenadas pero no se cómo recuperarlas !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un `var_dump($response)` para ver qué contiene.

De todos modos la estructura del `json` que devuelve normalmente trae un componente `status`, que si va correctamente es ok, y un `results` qué contiene los resultados.

El modo de acceder a latitud y longitud:

```
$lat = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$lon = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias Carmen... justo iba a colocar esa solución que logré obtener !!!

Comment: No hay de que MNibor, aunque haya llegado cuando ya lo encontraste :)